# Inline-block doesn't resize to children in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I am trying to create a custom, responsive image-map, in which the "area"-elements, represented by "a" tags, are styled with percentages. While the following code works in Chrome and Opera, I simply can't get the desired result with Firefox:

In Chrome and Opera, it behaves like it should (as I understand) by sizing the outer div with the class "map-wrapper" to the image's size. Firefox though will always make "map-wrapper" full width, even though it is clearly styled to behave like "inline-block".

FIDDLE:
[Code example](https://jsfiddle.net/Zero_Kucki/umujuLyw/)

HTML:

```
    <div class="map-container">
  <div class="map-wrapper">
    <img src="hhttps://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/1611/ChicagoClouds_Hersch_3600.jpg" usemap="map">
    <a class="img-map-event" href="#"></a>
    <a class="img-map-event" href="#"></a>
    <a class="img-map-event" href="#"></a>
    <a class="img-map-event" href="#"></a>
    <a class="img-map-event" href="#"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
img{
  height: 100%;
}
.map-container{
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.map-wrapper{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  max-height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

The desired result is that the "map-wrapper" is always perfectly surounding it's child and addapts the width and height of it.

I'm realy looking forward in solving this issue, so thank you for reading.

Comment: Could we see the styles for `.img-map-event` as well? (note: the image's URL has an extra H in the beginning)

Comment: After removing the h in the fiddle, I can't really see much difference between browsers.

Comment: @MrLister The additional H in the src only killed to link for the image, while the problem still exists. I figured out, that 100% in Firefox will set the img height to it's real height, while Chrome was limiting it with scale. Adding the style "height: calc(100vh - Ypx);" to the picture will make it work as intended. Thanks for the help, though :)

Comment: @chriskirknielsen The styling for the ".img-map-event"s are incidental and mostly static to a specific picture. It will use "margin-left" and "-top" with "position: absolute" to be positioned above desired location of the image. It's basically a custom image-map.

Comment: Strange though, because on my machine, Chrome and Firefox don't scale the image in the jsfiddle differently. That's what I was trying  to say.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that Chrome's 100% height on images works differently than Firefox's 100%. Firefox will definitly scale to 100% of the images size while Chrome will scale to the available space.

Adding the style "height: calc(100vh - Y px);" to the image will always scale to the available space on the webpage, leading to desired result.